# How to check if the key exists in Redis?

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I have a function in Laravel model and I need to check if my key ($key variable) exists in Redis, in other words I want to make a condition to not allow for duplicate results from redis. Here is my function. Any help is appreciated.

function

```
public static function cacheFields($fields)
{
    foreach ($fields as $fieldname => $values) {

        $key = static::$redisFieldKey.$fieldname; // here is that variable

        Redis::pipeline(function ($pipe) use ($key, $values) {
            foreach ($values as $value => $label) {
                $pipe->hset($key, $value, $label);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part will be duplicated ? hashes and hash keys are are unique

Comment: $key = static::$redisFieldKey.$fieldname;  I encountered that sometimes this gets duplicated

Answer (score 7):

When you execute `hset` for non existing key, it will `set` your hash with the field and its corresponding value. When you execute it against the existing hash (and field key), it will `update` the hash value of existing hash field.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hset myhash myhashfield myvalue
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall myhash
1) "myhashfield"
2) "myvalue"
127.0.0.1:6379> hset myhash myhashfield anothervalue
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall myhash
1) "myhashfield"
2) "anothervalue"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Still if you want to check whether the key exists, you may use `exists` O(1)

```
127.0.0.1:6379> exists myhash
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> exists nonexisting
(integer) 0
```

If you want to check whether the hash field exists, you may use `hexists` O(1)

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hexists myhash myhashfield
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> hexists myhash nonfield
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> hexists notmyhash myfield
(integer) 0
```

Edit:

The [documentation](https://redis.io/commands/hset) states that for `hset`;

> Sets field in the hash stored at key to value. If key does not exist, a new key holding a hash is created. If field already exists in the hash, it is overwritten.